# Is there a way to retrieve all users that have a particular password

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I am using [Laravel's Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing) functionality to store encrypted passwords in the table.

I know that I can use `Hash::check` function to check if a plain password matches the encrypted password, But is there a way to retrieve all users from the database that have a given password without actually getting all users and then comparing each one's password using the `Hash::check` function?

**Edit**:

The usecase is that I want to know how many users use a given password.

Comment: I don't know whether there is, but I certainly don't hope so, the issues that could cause would be insane.

Comment: First, why would you want to do that? Second, it can't be done. Each password has a unique salt and even if 1 million users have a password of **123456** you won't get the same password hash.

Comment: @TheFallen I have updated the question with more details about the usecase.

Comment: @Sudar Your update doesn't really add anything. We know you want to know that. We're unclear on *why*.

Comment: @Sudar Better make sure that your users don't find out, because I promis you, they are NOT gonna like the fact that you are checking their passwords.

Comment: Check the answers below, you can't get 2 same password hashes because of the unique salt.

Comment: @Epodax Well, they get pissed when you don't check passwords too. :-p http://techcrunch.com/2011/06/20/dropbox-security-bug-made-passwords-optional-for-four-hours/

Comment: @ceejayoz Not exactly what I ment, but oh well.

Comment: @Epodax I know, I'm just being a pedantic pain in the ass. Your point is very valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not without fetching all users and checking each individually. Laravel's password hashing uses [`bcrypt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (as does PHP's native `password_hash` / `password_verify`), which is specifically engineered to make this sort of thing difficult to do (for [security / protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables)) - it uses a different salt every time so no two hashes are the same even if the passwords are identical.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's such function in Laravel's hashing but seems unlikely because hashes, by definition, doesn't have 1-1 relation with the plain password.

I mean, multiple passwords can have the same hash, and if it Laravel Hashing uses salt (wich is likely because is a basic security pattern), the same password doesn't even have the same hash for all users.

It's unlikely to have such functionality, but in case it has, you can be sure that, under the hoods, it will do exactly the same that you have said: loop the users and use Hash::check on each one. Because hashing is intentionally designed in order that's the only way to do that.